# Side Loading on IOS Device

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, sideloading

I have a Question regarding side loading apps created with React Native (Expo).

I have build my app and uploaded it on the Expo Servers. I managed to side load the App on an Android Device without any problems. Even Over the Air updates run perfectly!

Now my question is if someone has ever managed to side load an app on an IOS Device? Is this even possible?

Its pretty simple on Android but as I know IOS it wont be easy on there because they always make your life extra hard :D

If someone has a guide or some reference on how to side load an Expo app I would really appreciate it.

Edit: I checked out this link: https://docs.expo.io/distribution/building-standalone-apps/ - which says that it can be done with XCode somehow.

As I dont have a Mac and I never want to own a Mac is it possible to do this via a VM maybe?

Thanks  ~Faded

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard if you have Xcode.  There's a few steps here, but it's not difficult.

- Do an archive build in Xcode.
- Right click the build in Xcode->Archive and select "Show in Finder"
- Right click the .xcarchive in Finder frand "Show Package Contents"
- Navigate to Product->Applications.  There will be a .app file in there.

Connect your phone to your Mac if you haven't already

- Open Xcode->Devices & Simulators
- Select your phone
- Drag the .app from the Finder onto the "INSTALLED APPS". This will install the app on the device

Sorry, just reread the OP.  I guess if you can get the xcarchive or .app from Expo you should be able to side load it using the last few steps

Comment: Yeah in the link its mentioned that you can get an archieve file - do you think if I would have such a file I could just load it onto an IOS Device without the need to change some code in XCode or some dependecies? Because I might try something like this with a Macbook of a friend someday

Comment: yeah, I think so (as long as you unpack it to get to the .app file).  If you have that, you could just open the Xcode devices window and copy the app file in there.

Answer (score 0):

There are few options to load app but they require either macOS system or paid Apple developer account.

- You can build in xcode if you have access to native sources, so it wouldn't work with expo managed workflow, but it's possible if you eject. (macOS required)
- You can create simulator build `expo build:ios -t simulator` (it will work only on simulator) (macOS required)
- You can create adhoc provisioning profile and use it for build, it will be possible to install that app only on devices registered on your apple account. (requires paid Apple developer account)
- You can side-load builds if you have enterprise Apple account

Comment: If I would eject the App and just build it with XCode - is it possible to load it on the Device then yes? But I guess I would have to do all optimazations for Apple in Xcode then too.

Comment: Also REAL Side Loading like on Android seems to only be enabled with a enterprise account as you wrote.. wich means 200$ every year

Comment: I'm not sure if the first solution would work with macos in vm. Third option is probably best for your use case.